# Retrieving value from dynamically created entry Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, controls

I'm dynamically adding Entry controls to StackLayout

```
    private void AddEntry_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Entry newEntry = new Entry();

        SplitterEntries.Children.Add(newEntry);
    }
```

And I want to retrieve each individual value on button click. I'm still learning c# and Xamarin Forms, and I'm not sure what is the best practice for this situation. Every help and advice is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to make the scope bigger.

Your `newEntry` variable is now local to the method it resides in. When you declare your `newEntry` outside of the method, you can also access it in other methods. For instance:

```
Entry _newEntry = new Entry();

private void AddEntry_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SplitterEntries.Children.Add(_newEntry);
}

private void OtherMethod()
{
    string currentValue = _newEntry.Text;
}
```